# Django. M2M field with throug model vs. manual intermediate model?

Tags: django, django-models

What are the advantages of using **many to many field with through model** versus **manually creating the intermediate model**? Let me use the example in the documentation:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

The tables created in Postgresql, in my case, and the admin page in Django would be the same as the ones created with:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
##  members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

The main advantage I found is that it is possible to create a inline form set at the admin page and the serializers may be easier; but a part from that, as I see, technically both options are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Another advantage is that you have a shortcut in `Group`.
You can retrieve all members from a group just by doing :

```
group.members.all()
```

instead of :

```
Person.objects.filter(membership__group=group)
```